# string в int и обратно

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i < 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i+"* 7 = ");
            int a = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            String c;
            if (a == i * 7)
                Console.WriteLine("правильно");
            else if (c = Int32.Parse(a) == "дальше") // тут не хочет приобразовывать инт в стринг
                continue;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("нет, ответ равен = " + i * 7);

            i++;
        }
```

Сначала я вывел стринг в инт, но мне нужно чтобы если я не хочу отвечать на очередной вопрос мог его пропустить командой, но обратно из итна в стринг он уже не хочет переходить, подскажите как правильно сделать чтобы все заработало?

Comment: `Int32.Parse(a) == "дальше"` возможно, я не понимаю C#, но по-моему здесь вы пытаетесь сравнить число со словом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам удалось преобразовать строку, введенную пользователем, в число, то бессмысленно сравнивать строковое представление этого числа со строкой, которая числом не является.

Не говоря уже о том, что параметром `Int32.Parse` должна быть строка, а не целое.

А если пользователь действительно ввел "дальше", то первый `Int32.Parse` выбросит `Exception` и на этом все закончится.

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " * 7 = ");

string response = Console.ReadLine();
if (response == "дальше")
{
  i++;
  continue;
}

int a;
if(!int.TryParse(response, out a))
{
  Console.WriteLine("not a number");
  continue;
}

if (a == i * 7)
  Console.WriteLine("правильно");
else
  Console.WriteLine("нет, ответ равен = " + i * 7);

i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример.

```
string a = "110";    
int num = Convert.ToInt32(a, 10); //Из string в int
string back = num.ToString(); //Из int в string
```